# Can you flatten HSMs with entry and exit behavior?

Tags: state-machine

Is there a way to flatten this Hierarchical State Machine ([HSM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZAVz.png)) to a Finite State Machine (FSM)? I have read HSMs can be flattened to FSMs, but I can't think of a way to do it with entry and exit behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This is no problem. I consider HSMs to be a special case of FSMs (with a "smart" convention how to draw/specify them).

As for the entry and exit actions, UML2 specifies in which order to sort them.